# Javascript file is not updated in development with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I changed a JS file under app/assets/javascripts but it is still the same. I deleted the file and re-created but the content is still the old one. This is my development.rb file:

```
App::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "lvh.me:3000" }

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  # config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  config.log_tags = [:uuid, :remote_ip]
end
```

The JS file is loaded inside the header tag with this code:

```
<script src="/assets/deals.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which is the normal way JS is loaded in development

Comment: did you try to see the code inside the `deals.js` change or not? How about try to restart your rails server?

Comment: restarting does not change anything

Comment: @rtacconi You can click the green arrow below the answer to mark it as correct. Certainly worked for me.

Answer (score 23):

Try to clear precompiled assets:

```
bundle exec rake assets:clean
```

Comment: Came here from Google - this answer is what worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Try to delete the tmp folder and then restart the server - rails s. 
That will do it.

Answer (score 3):

bundle exec rake assets:clean and then bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Comment: Can you please clarify more what this solution is

Comment: `assets:clean` clears out the 'old' compiled assets in your local environment and `assets:precompile` runs the assets compilation. Also `assets:clobber` clears all compiled assets, old and new

Comment: It seems crazy that I need to clear precompiled assets EVERY time I make a js change...

Comment: Does anyone know if there s a faster way to do it? Without precompiling the assets and then having to restart the containers EVERY time there is a js change

Comment: @Dr.FreddyDimethyltryptamine Seems like you are not running the server in development mode. In development mode, rails calls webpacker to do the compiling on every request (if there are any changes). Use the command: `RAILS_ENV=development rails server`

Answer (score 0):

Or delete the `public/assets` folder, and restart the app

Answer (score 0):

#### Check for `sprockets-rails` gem

In my case I upgraded to Rails 7, and for some reason, the javascript files were not updated. Spent many hours trying to work out why.

I finally discovered the culprit - in my case - somehow, I had removed the `sprockets-rails` gem. I could have easily lost many months trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue in my app running Rails 6 and 7. When I add `console.log` into one of the javascript controllers there won't be any log in the browser console, and it looks like the `console.log` is not even there.

I have been having issue for quite some time and have not been able to pinpoint the exact reason, it might be due to bundler installed globally, conflict between rvm and asdf, config for overmind, yarn or npm. But I found the 3 commands that resolve this problem for some time and I usually run them one after another

```
rails assets:clobber
rake tmp:cache:clear
rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 0):

Another unlikely cause is having the following config in development:

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

Although it is not the intention of the setting, it can stop modules from reloading and therefore stop the js bundle from updating without restarting the rails server as they have all been cached